# why do LINQ To SQL proxy classes sometimes implement INotifyPropertyChanging and INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm using the "Object Relational Designer" to create entities for my SQL database tables.

Question: why some classes implements `INotifyPropertyChanging`, `INotifyPropertyChanged` and others don't?

A problem appeared when I wanted to update some data in my database using LINQ To SQL entity that doesn't implements`INotifyPropertyChanging`, `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

entity defeniion:

```
 [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.user_to_user")]
public partial class user_to_user
{       
    private int _user_id1;

    private int _user_id2;

    private string _relation_type;

    public user_to_user()
    {
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_user_id1", DbType="Int NOT NULL")]
    public int user_id1
    {
        get
        {
            return this._user_id1;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._user_id1 != value))
            {
                this._user_id1 = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_user_id2", DbType="Int NOT NULL")]
    public int user_id2
    {
        get
        {
            return this._user_id2;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._user_id2 != value))
            {
                this._user_id2 = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_relation_type", DbType="VarChar(50) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
    public string relation_type
    {
        get
        {
            return this._relation_type;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._relation_type != value))
            {
                this._relation_type = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DataContext:

```
private Table<user_to_user> friendsTable = new BSocialDBDataContext().GetTable<user_to_user>();
```

then I try:

```
public void FriendshipOffer(int visitor_id, int owner_id)
    {
        var relation = friendsTable.FirstOrDefault(u => (u.user_id2 == visitor_id && u.user_id1 == owner_id));
        relation.relation_type = "friend";

        friendsTable.Context.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the designer implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` only if the table has a Primary Key.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).